# Got Error when data is inserted into SQL database from two End point (Web API and MVC site)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

When the data is inserted from two endpoint WebAPI and MVC site getting error however when data is inserted only from site not getting the below error,when the API is inserted the data after few row insertion got below error-

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider
>   failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Connection
>   Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to
>   consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be
>   because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to
>   respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect
>   to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=543; handshake=22278; 
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Below is the code of MVC:

```
    internal int SaveCompaignEmailStatusList(List<CampaignEmailStatu> emailStatusList)
    {
        using (GoonjDataModel db = new GoonjDataModel())
        {
            db.CampaignEmailStatus.AddRange(emailStatusList);
            return db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

And here the code of API:

```
                    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
                    string messageIdT = json.mail.messageId;
                    foreach (var item in deliveryList)
                    {
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                            {
                                cmd.Connection = con;
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                cmd.CommandText = "SP_INSERT_DELIVERY_REPORTS";
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportType", item.ReportType);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Campaign", item.Campaign);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", item.Email);
                                con.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.CommandText = "SP_UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_STATUS";
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@messageid", messageIdT);
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
```

Any solution would be very helpful..

Comment: You're possibly trying to open a _lot_ of connections here and the server is at some point still trying to handle this overhead. Look into reusing connections with a ConnectionPool.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sqlserver?

Answer (score 0):

By the exception it looks either SQL Server exhaust all the available connection pool OR it eats up all the server resources to the point where it becomes unresponsive. Can you open task manager and see the memory and CPU usage? when you are getting this exception. Also use below query to see how many active connection you have at that time when you are getting exceptions.

```
SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) AS DBName,
COUNT(dbid) AS NumberOfConnections,
loginame
FROM    sys.sysprocesses
GROUP BY dbid, loginame
ORDER BY DB_NAME(dbid)
```

Use following link for more info https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/24/sql-server-how-to-see-active-sql-server-connections-for-database/